# Finding if something exists in a related table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table employees and a table sales which are in a one-to-many relationship. Employees would contain fields such as name, email, id etc. and sales would include information such as country, number of sales, employeeID etc.

What I want to do now is find if for each and every employee if an entry in the sales table exists for a specific country.

My output should look something like

Employee.name, Employee.email, Sold to Canada

In "Sold to Canada" I simply want to put in a 1 or 0, depending on if for each employee there is an entry in sales where the condition for a specific country is met.

What I already tried out is this:

```
    SELECT emp.name
      ,emp.email
      ,(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sales sa JOIN employee emp ON emp.ID = sales.employeeID
      WHERE sales.country = 'Canada') as "Sold to Canada" 
FROM employee emp
```

This results in "Sold to Canada" being filled with a number much higher than 1, as I assume it returns the total number of employees that have made sales to Canada as opposed to the Information for each specific employee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to skin a cat. One of the better ones is below:

```
SELECT emp.name, emp.email, ISNULL( Sold, 0 ) AS [Sold to Canada]
FROM employee AS emp
    LEFT JOIN 
            ( SELECT 1 AS Sold, employeeID
            FROM sales
            WHERE sales.country = 'Canada'
            GROUP BY employeeID ) AS CanadaSales
        ON emp.ID = CanadaSales.employeeID
```

Comments:

It is not a good idea to use correlated sub-queries in the `SELECT` part as this may result in inefficient query plans and therefore slow query performance.

**Update:**
If you need to return results for multiple countries I would use [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
SELECT emp.name, emp.email, ISNULL( Canada, 0 ) AS SoldCanada, ISNULL( Australia, 0 ) AS SoldAustralia /*, ISNULL( [another country], 0 ) AS [Sold Yet another country] */
FROM employee AS emp
    LEFT JOIN 
        ( SELECT *
        FROM
            ( 
                -- List of Country Employees
                SELECT 1 AS Sold, employeeID, country
                FROM sales
                GROUP BY employeeID, country ) AS EmpCountrySales
            PIVOT
            (
                -- For each country present return 1, else NULL
                MAX( Sold ) FOR country IN( [Canada], [Australia] /* , [another country] */ ) 
            ) AS pvt
        ) AS EmployeeSales

        ON emp.ID = EmployeeSales.employeeID
```

Comments:
`PIVOT` function requires too many brackets.

Comment: Wow, this solution is blazing fast! Compared to using `Case When` this performed like 100 times faster

Can I just extend it by adding further joins if I want to look at multiple countries? I tried it and it seems to work just fine, but I want to make sure that this is the right approach to take.

Answer (score 3):

@Alex has already given a great answer. However, you can use this solution if you want to avoid sub-queries.

```
SELECT MIN(e.Name) AS EmployeeName
    , MIN(e.Email) AS Email
    , CASE WHEN MIN(EmployeeID) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [Sold To Canada]
FROM Employee AS e
LEFT JOIN Sales AS s ON (s.EmployeeID = e.ID AND Country = 'Canada')
GROUP BY e.ID;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with `CASE`:

```
SELECT emp.name,
    emp.email,
    (CASE WHEN emp.ID IN (SELECT sales.employeeID FROM sales WHERE sales.country = 'Canada') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Sold to Canada]
FROM employee emp
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a direct translation into SQL using a *Correlated Subquery* :-)

```
SELECT emp.name
      ,emp.email
      ,CASE
         WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sales sa 
                     WHERE emp.ID = sa.employeeID
                       AND sa.country = 'Canada')
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END as "Sold to Canada" 
FROM employee emp
```